# Shortest way to return list o ffiles using WHERE condition

Tags: c#, list

I am reading all the file names at given location using following code -

```
return new DirectoryInfo(location).GetFiles().Select(o => o.Name).ToArray();
```

But then I want to have list of specific file types. What would be best shortest way to achive somthing like following -

```
return new DirectoryInfo(location).GetFiles().Select(o => o.Name.Contains("csv")).ToArray();
```

I have tried this code, but obvisouly it does not work.

Comment: You don't filter with `Select` - you filter with `Where`... (just as in your title!)

Comment: You have put `Where` in your question title, so why not put a `Where` in your LINQ query?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use a [searchPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

```
return new DirectoryInfo(location).GetFiles("*.csv")
```

Comment: Quite good but does not extend to filtering on TimeStamnps etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not Select, but Where: (and string.EndsWith instead of string.Contains)

```
return new DirectoryInfo(location).GetFiles().Where(o => o.Name.EndsWith(".csv")).ToArray();
```

Comment: and probably a ToList is better

Comment: it's better to use Extension rather then EndsWith.

Comment: Instead of `EndsWith` use `Path.GetExtension`, but in this case since `o` is already a `FileInfo` you ccan use the `Extension` property directly..

Comment: Ok, Extension would be better.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use below mentioned code.
rather then checking name you can check extension of file

```
new DirectoryInfo("C").GetFiles().Where(o => o.Extension.Contains("csv")).ToArray();
```